# VLOOKUP is malfunctioning in Excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have been working on this issue for over two hours and I am beginning to question my sanity. I have used vlookup many times in the past, but now it is just not working as expected. I am trying to replicate a LEFT-JOIN (from SQL) in Excel using vlookup.

Here is the formula I am using on cell `G2`:

[image]

Here is the table of all the values I want to lookup values for.

[image]

Here is the table I am using as a reference:

[image]

I am only searching one column to simplify the example. Cell `G2` contains the formula which is applied to the cells under it as well. As you can see from the first image, not only is it not matching but there is some pretty weird behavior going on.

1. I have removed duplicates for both tables.
2. I have unformatted the data to plain text values
3. I have tried this formula on three different computers

Regardless, I keep kept getting the same result! I am starting to lose sanity.

Does anyone have any idea? 
Thank you

Comment: Since `range_lookup` is `TRUE`, the first column *(A368:A697)* **must** be sorted in Ascending order. The formula will then return an approximate match if an exact match is not present.

Comment: So where do you currently stand on this issue, @PaulTrimor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want exact matches, you should be using FALSE as the last parameter

Comment: Even if I use FALSE, I still get unexpected values

Comment: I actually get `#VALUE` errors for most of them. With an occasional `#NA` error for every like 10 `#VALUE` errors.

Comment: Possibly it's treating it like a number somewhere.  Try:  =VLOOKUP("" & A2, $A$368:$A697, 1, FALSE)

Comment: #N/A means that the value is not found in the lookup table. If you see #VALUE! then double check your formulas and your data. You should not get a Value error with FALSE as the last parameter. With TRUE as the last parameter, the VALUE error means your search term is smaller than the first value.

Comment: Yes, I just got back to work this morning and tested =VLOOKUP("" & A2, $A$368:$A697, 1, FALSE) . And IT WORKED!

Answer (score 1):

The lookup table must be sorted in ascending order. Cell A369 appears to have a value lower than the row before it, A368. There are several instances of "lower" values occurring after a higher value.

Before you go insane, consider sorting the range $A$368 thru $A$679, and see if that makes a difference.

Otherwise, time to ditch `VLOOKUP`, and use instead `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

Comment: Index/Match won't solve the underlying problem. Match also needs a sorted range if the last parameter is TRUE. The problem here is that an exact match is desired, and for that the fourth Vlookup parameter must be FALSE to avoid wrong results, while at the same time the sort order becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Even with a sorted data table, if you use TRUE, the lookup will return the next smallest match if no exact match is found. This can lead to wrong results if an exact match is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can get the `#N/A` error if your `lookup_value` isn't "clean". If that's the case, try this formula:

`=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN(A2)),$A$368:$A$697,1,FALSE)`

Additionally, your `table_array` may have "unclean" data, so you'll need to scrub that first before you're able to find a match. To do that, use this **array** formula, committing it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,TRIM(CLEAN($A$368:$A$697)),1,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a MATCH?  does it need to be VLOOKUP?

if you are happy using match try:

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,$A$368:$A$697,0),A2,"NO MATCH")
```